# Can’t connect to any local servers when on local network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, firewall, port-forwarding

This has probably been asked a million times, so I apologise if this is a duplicate of my issues. However looking at other asks haven’t been good enough for me, so I’ll ask myself.
I have several servers ranging different applications on my home network (XMPP, IRC, Web, etc), and they’re all port forwarded. Let’s say my IP is `12.345.678.90`. (this is OBVIOUSLY not a real IP) Server A has a local IP of `192.168.0.123` and has SSH running on port 38. If I’m on the local network and I SSH into `ssh 192.168.0.123:38`, it connects just fine. But if I SSH into `12.345.678.90:38`, it either loads forever, then it either times out, or it loads and is extremely slow. But if I go to my office (or literally anywhere else) and connect to `12.345.678.90:38`, it works just fine. We used to not have this issue, but then we got a new modem because the old one game out, and now it’s doing this. Any ideas of what settings I might need to change on the modem?
(Sidenote: this is true with both internal static IPs and dynamic IPs)

ISP is Frontier and modem is an ARRIS NVG468MQ.
Cheers :)

Comment: Seems your router does not have NAT hairpinning feature, so you MUST connect to the LAN server with the local LAN IPs and to access the services on the Public IP you MUST be outside of your LAN network.

Comment: @Zina that seems to be it, thank you! (Odd... the old Verizon modem we had for like 6 years had NAT loopback, but this new and “better” one doesn’t...)